# Print or grep lines which start from second column

Tags: linux, grep, text-editing

I want to print lines which start from second column (first column is white space).

```
$ cat test.txt

first
 second
  third
   four
 second
    five
      seven
```

Output should be:

```
 second


 second
```

When the line starts from the 7th column then the output should be:

```
      seven
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `^\s\S` regex:

```
$ cat test.txt
first
 second
  third
   four
 second
    five
      seven
$ grep "^\s\S" test.txt
 second
 second
```

- `^` stands for "line starts with",
- `\s` means "first character is a white space",
- `\S` for "following character is not a whitespace.

This way, you get every line beginning with a single whitespace.

If you want lines beginning with `n` whitespaces, add `{n}`:

```
$ grep "^\s\{1\}\S" test.txt
 second
 secon d
$ grep "^\s\{2\}\S" test.txt
  third
$ grep "^\s\{3\}\S" test.txt
   four
$ grep "^\s\{4\}\S" test.txt
    five
$ grep "^\s\{5\}\S" test.txt
$ grep "^\s\{6\}\S" test.txt
      seven
```

Answer (score 0):

Really simple solution for the second version:

```
 echo "first
 second
  third
   four
 second
    five
      seven" | grep -e '^ ' | grep -ve '^  '
```

[Edit] - now working with only the withespaces at the begining of the line

Comment: What if a line contains multiple spaces (for example, `second` is replaced with `second  line`)?

Comment: Correct, added that - Anyway, you solution is much cleaner @ssssteffff